# Iterate through Key/Values in D3 graph for line chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

This is a pretty simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have an enormous JSON (about 50,000 lines big) where each section contains a 90th percentile value, a timer name, and a couple other useless pieces of data.

I am trying to make graphs out of the 90th percentile, where the timer name is the same.  I used the code found in [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-multi-line-chart-using-d3js-part-2--cms-22973) to group all the timer names are the same.  Here is the code to do that:

```
var dataGroup = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){
        return d.timerName;
    })
    .entries(info);
```

So now the JSON is grouped by key/value pair like this:

```
[{
   "key": "Timer1",
   "values": [{
       "timerName": "Timer1",
       "ninetieth": "202",
       "year": "2000"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer1",
       "ninetieth": "215",
       "year": "2002"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer1",
       "ninetieth": "179",
       "year": "2004"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer1",
       "ninetieth": "199",
       "year": "2006"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer1",
       "ninetieth": "134",
       "year": "2008"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer1",
       "ninetieth": "176",
       "year": "2010"
   }]
}, {
   "key": "Timer2",
   "values": [{
       "timerName": "Timer2",
       "ninetieth": "100",
       "year": "2000"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer2",
       "ninetieth": "215",
       "year": "2002"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer2",
       "ninetieth": "179",
       "year": "2004"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer2",
       "ninetieth": "199",
       "year": "2006"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer2",
       "ninetieth": "134",
       "year": "2008"
   }, {
       "timerName": "Timer2",
       "ninetieth": "176",
       "year": "2013"
  }]
}]
```

I just need help figuring out how to go through and make a separate line chart for each 'key' if that makes sense.  So I need a graph for Timer1 with the values for the line chart being all 6 of the 'ninetieth' values under the key named "Timer1".

If anyone can help, that would be amazing!!!  Here's the code that I have so far (it creates the box where the graph should be, including tick marks and everything, but no line actually appears on it): http://jsfiddle.net/fsx9o8c5/

[image]

Comment: Do you want something like this http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/iris-parallel.html/ or http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955?

Comment: @BrantOlsen The first link doesn't work, but the second example isn't quite right.  I just edited my post to add a picture of what I need - it's not correct though because it has all the lines from the different key values but I just need one line per graph.

Comment: If my answer does not work for you, could you please update your fiddle? It gives an error with URLtoJSON is not defined. If you could hard code some sample data to be used would help.

Comment: I removed my answer since you do not use the `a` variable in any functions and thus do not have a scope issue. Could you please update your fiddle so that it actually creates the six graphs that you are seeing.

Comment: @BrantOlsen Sorry I forgot I added a piece of data before I took the picture.  Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fsx9o8c5/2/       Thank you for helping me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fsx9o8c5/6/

I have updated your fiddle to what I beileve you want.

The main change was

```
dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i){
  graph.append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', line(d.values))
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
});
```

to

```
graph.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', line(data))
        .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('fill', 'none');
```

Since you only want to append the current data into the current graph.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I knew I was close... You are awesome, Brant, thank you!!